# CSS to place input(textboxes) across from each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the second textbox to be across from the first one. Right it is at the bottom righthand side.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h2>Top</h2>
         <div>
            <h2>TextBox 1</h2>
            <div>
               <input type="text" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="float:right;">
            <h2>textbox2</h2>
            <div>
               <input type="text" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is adding `float: left;` to the first container div, as this shrinks its width to the width of its content, allowing both inputs to appear side by side.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwFyp/

Comment: Don't forget to add a "clearfix" class and apply it to the wrapping parent div, so that styles will be applied as expected.   .clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

Answer (score 1):

Just float the first one left

```
<div style="float:left;">
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhP4T/)

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to float both of the divs containing your h2 and input elements. You can either float both left or float the first one left and the second one right (as in this example from your code above):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Top</h2>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <h2>TextBox 1</h2>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <h2>textbox2</h2>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Floating both div's left would position the second div right after the first one.

You might also find you need to put a clearing div `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` immediately after your second floating div. This will prevent elements following these two from being positioned immediately after the last floated element.

Answer (score 0):

floating divs for alignment of inputs gets tricky messy with lots of extra code try this cleaner approach that can be styled via CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        .horz-inputs label, .horz-inputs input {display: inline-block;}
        /*add any css you want to the inputs and labels from this point forward
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="horz-inputs">
            <h2>Top</h2>
            <label>TextBox 1</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <label>TextBox 2</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```